# NestJS can't resolve dependency of a custom repository after updating from version 7 to 8

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

My CidadesService isn't able to import the custom repository of Cidades entity. I followed the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#custom-repository) and the project was working fine for months before updating from Nest 7 to Nest 8, I'm not sure if there was a breaking change that I missed.

If I add CidadesRepository into the providers array of CidadesModule the program works fine but that shouldn't be needed, CidadesService should be able to resolve the depency only using the @InjectRepository decorator.

app.module:

```js
@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(typeOrmConfig),
        CidadesModule,
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService, SwaggerGenerator, { provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR, useClass: LoggingInterceptor }],
})
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private connection: Connection) {}
}
```

cidades.module:

```js
@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Cidades])],
    controllers: [CidadesController],
    providers: [CidadesService], // If I add CidadesRepository here code works fine
})
export class CidadesModule {}
```

cidades.controller:

```js
@Controller('cidades')
export class CidadesController {
    constructor(private cidadesService: CidadesService) {}
}
```

cidades.service:

```js
@Injectable()
export class CidadesService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(CidadesRepository)
        private cidadesRepository: CidadesRepository
    ) {}
}
```

cidades.repository:

```js
@EntityRepository(Cidades)
export class CidadesRepository extends Repository<Cidades> {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the issue; my code wasn't following the documentation properly. For injecting a custom repository the imports array should import the custom repository instead of the entity.

So cidades.module should be this:

```js
@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([CidadesRepository])],
    controllers: [CidadesController],
    providers: [CidadesService],
})
export class CidadesModule {}
```

Furthermore cidades.service does not need the @InjectRepository decorator (but also works if I leave it):

```js
@Injectable()
export class CidadesService {
    constructor(
        private cidadesRepository: CidadesRepository
    ) {}
}
```

Not sure if somehow I messed up from the start but the project worked for months anyways or the way to import changed, but my issue seems to be resolved.

I still can't respond my answer so it's left open if anyone has any futher comments.